# Taking additional parameters while using OmniAuth without Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

Hi I am using omniauth in my application. I created the application without using devise. So I wrote all the methods for encryption manually. I am trying to integrate imniauth with my application but I am encountering loads of problems. I made an authentications controller:

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
  end

  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication= Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'],omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      flash[:notice]= "Signed in with " + omniauth['provider'] + " Successfully"
      sign_in(authentication.user)
      redirect_back_or authentication.user
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'],:uid => omniauth['uid'])
      flash[:notice]="authentication successfull"
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else

   authenticate= Authentication.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
   flash[:notice] = "You still need to fill up the following"
   # This is where I have doubt as to how should I proceed. Should I first create authentication for omniauth and then redirect or just send everything together and then create in sign up?
   # session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
   #  redirect_to signup_path(omniauth)

 end
end

  def destroy
    @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication."
    redirect_to authentications_url
  end
end
```

My User controller is as follows:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:show, :new, :create]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy

# Id ont know what to do with omniauth here! :( 
  def new(omniauth)
    @user  = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => "Welcome to the World Student Alliance!" }
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @title = "Edit user"
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => "Profile updated." }
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :flash => { :success => "User destroyed." }
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) if !current_user.admin? || current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

and sessions controller is as follows:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :check_sign_in, :only => [:new, :create]
  def new
    @title = "Sign in"
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Each user has many authentications and each authentication belongs to a user

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
.......
```

The following are the scenarios I considered:

1. User is logged in and wants to connect with his twitter. ( Completed without errors)
2. User is already a registered user and wants to use twitter for signing in every time( Completed without errors)
3. User is not registered and wants to use twitter for authentication. If its basic authentication then it is done but I need to make the user enter few details like country, gender, department etc. This is where everything is goign wrong. I am able to create an authentication and escape him to the sign in form but when user is signed in from fb or twitter he should not have to enter the password fields. This is my problem. Could anyone please let me know of what I should be doing to get over this error. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked out these Rails casts? http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

Comment: Yes! I did but I am not using omniauth.

Comment: I think you mean you're not using Devise.  There is another screencast for omniauth only: http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar in a recent application - using Omniauth for authentication and allowing multiple authentications per user.  For your case 3.) I create the user and the authentication first; then send them to a specific form (not the signup form) for filling out the rest of their profile.

This 'extra' form only comes into play if the required fields are not complete, otherwise they get redirected to the user show page.  Seems to work well for me.

Edit: replace your current username/password gubbins with the Omniauth Identiy strategy: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity.  This way you have all your authentication handled by Omniauth. Believe me, your life will be simpler if you take out your hand-made password authentication code and replace it with Omniauth identity.

For the avoidance of doubt, by having both Twitter and Identity strategies in place it means that you are giving your users a choice as to how they authenticate.  They may use either Twitter or username/password to authenticate.  Both get the same job done, however, if they use Twitter then you never see the password information (which is fine).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That was what I was trying to do too. But I need to be able to show the users just other details other than password. When I am trying to implement that it is breaking beacuse password cannot be blank. Do you think I should use a default password for all the users who are using omniauth to login? Is it a right approach?

Comment: I am little new to ruby and rails. I am using this for my semester project I would be really glad if you could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok.  Using Twitter for authentication (via Omniauth) is a substitute for using username/password for authentication.  The username/password combo is just another type of authentication so you should replace what you currently have with the Omniauth Identity strategy (so you are relying on Omniauth for both integration with Twitter as well as providing the username/password approach).

Comment: No! Twitter will not give me password at any cost. I was thinking of a way to make the password field null when user wants to use omniauth. I was thinking I will disable validations on user model for authenticating_using_omniauth function and make password null and prompt user to fill in rest of the details. Is this a right approach?

Comment: In case user is trying to signin next time using twitter I should be able to recognize the details of the user. I need little guidance in this part. Thank you.

Comment: I realise that twitter won't give you the password.  The thing is, you don't need a password field if you are using twitter for authentication.  I think you know that but are confused as to what to do with your password field that you are validating on your user model. My suggestion is to remove your hand-made password authentication code and replace it with Omniauth Identity.  That puts the mechanics of username/password authentication into Omniauth and you can remove your existing password model.

Comment: The way your app recognises a future signin from someone that has authenticated via Twitter before is by the unique id (uid) that is saved by your authentication model.